# Apply a EWMA rolling window function in Pandas but avoid initial NAN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe and subsequent EWMA function:

```
from functools import partial

#Create DF
d = {'Name': ['Jim', 'Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim','Jim',], 'col2': [5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


#EWMA 5
alpha = 1-np.log(2)/3 
window5 = 5
weights5 = list(reversed([(1-alpha)**n for n in range(window5)]))
ewma5 = partial(np.average, weights=weights5)

df1['Rolling5'] = df1.groupby('Name')['col2'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling(5).apply(ewma5))
df1
```

Which results in:

[image]

I have a specified a rolling window of 5 but does anyone know how can I get the EWMA to calculate in the first to 4th Row even though there arent 5 values?

EG for row 1, calculate for just row 1 (which would just be the same value) and then for row 2 it calculates the EWMA of rows 1 & 2. Also open to more efficient ways of doing this!

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ewm` and set `min_periods` in `rolling` to 1:

```
def f(x):
    return x.ewm(alpha=1-np.log(2)/3).mean().iloc[-1]

df1['Rolling5'] = df1.groupby('Name')['col2'].transform(
    lambda x: x.rolling(5, min_periods=1).apply(f))
```

---

Comparing with the original:

```
df1['Rolling5_original'] = df1.groupby('Name')['col2'].transform(
    lambda x: x.rolling(5).apply(ewma5))

df1['Rolling5'] = df1.groupby('Name')['col2'].transform(
    lambda x: x.rolling(5, min_periods=1).apply(f))

df1
```

Output:

```
  Name  col2  Rolling5_original  Rolling5
0  Jim     1                NaN  1.000000
1  Jim     2                NaN  1.812315
2  Jim     3                NaN  2.736992
3  Jim     4                NaN  3.710959
4  Jim     5           4.702821  4.702821
5  Jim     6           5.702821  5.702821
6  Jim     7           6.702821  6.702821
7  Jim     8           7.702821  7.702821
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close, if you specify the `min_periods=1`, the windows out of `rolling` will start from size 1 and then expand till 5 and stay there. As for the average, we will pass the weights' corresponding parts to cover the cases it will fall short:

```
weights = (1-alpha) ** np.arange(5)[::-1]

df["rolling_5"] = (df.col2
                     .rolling(5, min_periods=1)
                     .apply(lambda win: np.average(win, weights=weights[-win.size:]))
)
```

to get

```
  Name  col2  rolling_5
0  Jim     5        5.0
1  Jim     5        5.0
2  Jim     5        5.0
3  Jim     5        5.0
4  Jim     5        5.0
5  Jim     5        5.0
6  Jim     5        5.0
7  Jim     5        5.0
```

Comment: Aydin how would i do it with a groupby using `Name`? Thanks

Comment: I am getting `TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index` when trying `df1["rolling_5"] = (df1.groupby('Name')['col2'].rolling(5, min_periods=1).apply(lambda win: np.average(win, weights=weights[-win.size:])))`

Comment: @SOK You can chain a `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` at the end to drop the `Name` from the index that prevents the assignment, i.e., `df1["rolling_5"] = (df1.groupby("Name").col2.rolling(5, min_periods=1).apply(lambda win: np.average(win, weights=weights[-win.size:])).reset_index(level=0, drop=True))`.

Comment: @SOK But I'm a bit confused, because result of this answer and that of @perl doesn't match. I thought EWMA of a constant sequence (i.e., all 5s here) should be constant, too. How do you define your moving average exactly? But since you accepted @perl's answer, I guess that should be the way `:)`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i am trying to apply a rolling 5 winow, but i have multiple names so need it for a `groupby`. Also in the answer I accepted had different numbers in the dataframe, hence not constant of 5. I appreciate your help though!!